# The page keeps redirecting on logging out of the B2B Commerce Community Page. The same happens while loading it in Incognito Mode

Tags: community, b2b

Whenever I try to log out of the demo Capricorn Coffee StoreFront Community of the B2B Commerce Package,I get redirected too many times and the page fails to load.
The same problem arises when I try To open the storeFront from Incognito Browser.
The Guest User Settings are Configured as per the Salesforce Documentation

Comment: try firefox, or a new machine. Does it still happen?

Comment: Yup, in all kinds of browser and on different machines too.

Comment: hi Akshat, did it resolve?